# Issues with displaying an image in HTML

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>

           body, html {
              height: 100%;
              width: 100%;
           }

           .top {
               width: 800px;
               margin: 0 auto;
           }

           .topfixedimg{
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                background-image: url("image.jpg");
                background-position: center;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                height: 85%;
            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="top">
            <div class="topfixedimg"> </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I don't add the height attribute in the CSS of the outermost "top" div, the above code snippet does not display the image.

If I add height, then it displays the image correctly.

Should it not take the height from the CSS of inner div element and still display the image, even without the height attribute in the CSS of the outermost div element ?

Answer (score 8):

85% height means 85% of the height of parent. Since you're not specifying any height to outer div, its height is 0px and thus 85% of 0 is 0.

Either specify the height of parent, or specify the height of inner div in px, em, rem, etc.

```css
#outer {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
}

#inner {
width: 100px;
height: 50%;
background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
  <span>I'm just another element</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Let us say, I have a parent wrapper div (height: 100%) element that encloses all the elements in the body. And then there is another div inside it, which is displaying an image. If I make the height of the inner div = 85%, then doesn't it mean that this content alone is taking 85% of the height of the outer div?Then would it also mean, all the other content (other HTML elements) will only get to occupy, the remaining 15% of the space of the outer div ?

Comment: @livetolearn yes that is correct. I've put an example in the answer for your reference

Comment: Thank you, I ran it myself and I could see the difference. But what is confusing is that if I have a wrapper div and just one div within that wrapper div occupies 85% of the height, then all other elements are restricted to just 15% of the space. In this case, If I have really large images and text I will never be able to fit them ?

Comment: @livetolearn you can make your 15% div scrollable so as to fit more text in it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, let me try that ! thanks for your help and really quick answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The topfixedimg class has a height of 85%. This means display this element 85% of it’s parent (which in this instance is the ‘top’ div.

As the ‘top’ div doesn’t have a height set, it’s height is 0. So 85% of 0 is 0.